# Type Cast - C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, type-conversion

Why the last command is invalid? The compiler cant resolve.

```
class IRNode
class IINputBS
class ColumnReaderNode: public IRNode, public IInputBS

ColumReaderNode *col = new ColumnReaderNode();
IRNode *node = col;
IInputBS *bs2 = (IInputBS *)(col); //valid
IInputBS *bs1 = (IInputBS *)(node); //invalid
```

Comment: What is the specific error you are getting from the compiler? Also, don't use C-style casting in C++.

Comment: BTW, use `static_cast` instead of C-cast.  (or `dynamic_cast` if appropriate)

Comment: `IRNode` and `IINputBS` are unrelated, so can't be safety cast from each to other. (use as intermediary `ColumnReaderNode` should work...)

Comment: If i use reinterpret_cast everything works.. "The operation result is a simple binary copy of the value from one pointer to the other."

Comment: @Rubber Which, of course, is not what you actually want.

Comment: @Rubber please don't use `reinterpret_cast` ever... unless you are really sure that it does what you think it does. And even in that case, see if you don't have another way of doing what you want it to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bad idea to use C-style casts in C++ code, and here is why. If you were using C++ casts, the first one could be done with a `static_cast`, while the second one would require you to use a `reinterpret_cast` to build. And that should trigger a warning sign - a need to use `reinterpret_cast` with pointers usually means the compiler doesn't have enough information to do the proper cast.

That's exactly what's happening. Given just a `IRNode*`, there is no way to compute a `IInputBS*` out of it - they are not related. There could be arbitrarily many classes deriving from these two in arbitrarily complex ways, for example.

You have two options. If you know for certain that your object actually is of a type derived from both (such as `ColumReaderNode` in your case) and you just want to get at its other parent, you can use `static_cast` to downcast to this, and leave the rest to implicit conversions (or use a `static_cast` again, if you feel like it):

```
IInputBS *bs1 = static_cast<ColumnReaderNode*>(node); // upcast will happen implicitly

IInputBS *bs1 = static_cast<IInputBS*>(static_cast<ColumnReaderNode*>(node)); // explicit, but superfluous upcast
```

If you do not know for certain that the object is actually of type `ColumnReaderNode`, you can use `dynamic_cast`. This has a runtime cost, but it will actually do the right thing by inspecting the actual runtime type of the object you're pointing to:

```
IInputBS *bs1 = dynamic_cast<IInputBS*>(node);
```

This will do the correct cast if the object is of the appropriate type, or set `bs1` to a null value if not.

`dynamic_cast` requires the objects involved to be polymorphic (i.e. have at least one `virtual` member function), but I would assume this is already fulfilled in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Because `IRNode` and `IInputBS` are unrelated, so a pointer to one can't be cast to a pointer to the other.

The compiler can't tell what an `IRNode*` will point to at runtime.

That `col` is an instance of a class related to both these classes is information that you threw away when you cast it to an `IRNode`.

Comment: This cast actually can be done using `dynamic_cast`. The `dynamic_cast` will succeed if the underlying type being pointed to is compatible with the type being cast to, and will fail (resulting in a null pointer, or throwing an exception if casting references) if the underlying type is not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ `dynamic_cast` can be used to perform a cross-cast which will allow you to cast across a hierarchy.

```
class IRNode
class IINputBS
class ColumnReaderNode: public IRNode, public IInputBS

ColumnReaderNode *col = new ColumnReaderNode();
IRNode *node = col;
IInputBS *bs1 = dynamic_cast<IInputBS *>(node); // should work
```

The `dynamic_cast` will succeed in this case (though you may still want to assert that it does) since `node` actually does point to an `IInputBS` (since it is pointing to a `ColumnReaderNode`).

Comment: You forgot to mention that `dynamic_cast` only works if `IRNode` and `IInputBS` have `virtual` methods...

Comment: true, it also only works if RTTI is enabled. But I am currently under the assumption that `IRNode` and `IInputBS` are pure abstract interfaces with `virtual` methods.